# itertools does not recognize numpy ints as valid inputs on Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools

Take this code:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
data = ['a','b','c','d']
dw = np.array([1, 3], dtype=np.int64)
print(list(it.islice(data,dw[0],dw[1],1)))
```

On Python 2.7 it prints `['b', 'c',]` as expected.

On Python 3.6 it throws an exception:

```
ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.
```

The same goes for `np.int32`, and other methods of the `itertools` package throw similar errors, e.g. when you use `permutations` you get `TypeError: Expected int as r`.

I couldn't find much on this apart from  [this numpy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2951) and related ones, but that one was closed 3 years ago implying it was solved.

And basic things like indexing with numpy ints `data[dw[0]]` or boolean comparisons like `dw[0] == 1` work just fine.

Am I missing something? Could this be a Python 3 bug?

Comment: the simplest fix would be to use type casting: `int(dw[0]), int(dw[1])`

Comment: Even where it works, py2.7, the use an array instead of a list will slower.

Comment: Exactly the sort of thing that makes me hate Python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

a `numpy.int64` is apparently not a subclass of `int`

```
a, b = dw[0], dw[1]
```

> `type(a)`

```
numpy.int64
```

> `isinstance(a, int)`

```
False
```

## Numpy documentation

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) mentions this explicitly

> Warning
>
> The int_ type does not inherit from the int built-in under Python 3,
>   because type int is no longer a fixed-width integer type.

## Solution

```
print(list(it.islice(data, int(dw[0]) , int(dw[1]), 1)))
```

or numpy slicing

```
data[dw[0]:dw[1]:1]
```

Comment: Bless explicit type casting

Comment: So why does `itertools.islice` require `int`s while regular list slicing is fine without them (e.g. `data[dw[0]]`)?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Regular list slicing and indexing supports anything that implements the `__index__` method. NumPy integer types implement that method.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you; is there a reason for that design? Why not let `islice` support anything with the `__index__`  method too? Although perhaps there is no real need for this given how easy it is to cast to `int`...

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I think that's a question for bugs.python.org.

Comment: @Chris_Rands For `__index__`, it is the implementer of the class who decides what kinds of arguments are valid. I would bet that `[a,b][dw[0]:dw[1]:1]` does not accept `numpy.int64` either. I would bet that only numpy container types accept `numpy.int64` as arguments for slicing.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ok, a bug issue has been raised (not by me) http://bugs.python.org/issue30537

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it's a bug in Python 3 or not, but it looks like the behaviour has changed since 2.7.  As the [numpy issue you linked](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2951) described, under py27, either `numpy.int32` or `numpy.int64` would appear to be a subclass of `int` (depending on whether you use a 32- or 64-bit build of Python); under py3, the types are no longer related (numpy has fixed-width numeric types, python's `int` is variable-width).

The [implementation of `itertools.islice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L1403) requires its arguments to be objects of type PyLong ([which is the Python API name for the Python `int` type](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html)).  Specifically, it calls [`PyLong_AsSize_t`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/longobject.c#L605), which converts a Python object into a C `size_t` value.  This method seems to require that its argument is actually a Python `int` object, since it calls [`PyLong_Check`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Include/longobject.h#L14).  I think this method is broadly equivalent to Python's `isinstance(obj, int)`, which explains the difference in behaviour between py2 and py3 here.

[Normal list indexing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/listobject.c#L2410) uses another more tolerant method to coerce arguments into positive integer values, called [`PyNumber_AsSsize_t`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/abstract.c#L1255). 
 This checks if its argument is an `int`, and, if not, falls back to trying to call its argument's [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) method; as @MarkDickinson points out, numpy's numeric types implement this method, so everything works fine.  Perhaps this would be a more intuitive thing for `itertools.islice` to do.

Comment: Given that things like indexing or boolean comparisons work just fine shouldn't this considered to be a bug? Apparently many more basic functionalities are implemented in a way that works.

Comment: @Khris I'm personally inclined to view this as a shortcoming of `islice`, yes.  It would seem more sensible to have `islice` consume any argument which is in some way "numeric" (including, for example, the base type `np.integer`).

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a case for the `__index__` magic method (which numpy's integers already implement). I suggest raising an issue on the tracker, requesting this as an enhancement - that islice accept any object that implements `__index__`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep a `islice`/`slice`-like object, use `np.s_`:

```
slice = np.s_[dw[0]: dw[1]: 1]
data[slice]

['b', 'c']
```

since `np.s_` is a `numpy` object, it doesn't mind the `numpy` integers.

Comment: Regular slicing was never an issue; `list(it.islice(data,np.s_[dw[0]]))` still fails

Comment: The point is to skip creating an `iterable` object altogether and use a `numpy` object with equivalent function.  The reason why `itertools` fails is covered in other answers.

Comment: Thus the introductory phrase "If you want to keep a slice-like object".  i.e. if you're going to be using that slice on a bunch of different `list`s

Comment: But then why not just use `slice()` like `a = slice(dw[0],dw[1]); data[a]`?

Comment: . . . Because I had a completely unrelated error pop when I tried `slice()` and I assumed it was the same integer type mismatch.  Whoops.  `np.s_[]` still looks nicer, I guess!