# python 3, difference in two tuple constructions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples

I have a script for doing some math computations, where I am using dictionaries to represent polynomials. Originally my code started off as this:

```
p = {}
p[(0,0,0)] = 1
```

Then, to generalize, I replaced the second command by this:

```
p[tuple(numpy.zeros((3,),dtype=int))] = 1
```

What I do not understand is why this single change affects the outcome of the program.  How are these different?

Comment: I tested it, and there is no difference...

Comment: *"this single change affects the outcome of the program"* you'll need to explain this sentence.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I am getting different results after making the change. Let me see if I can get a smaller script to produce the same distinction

Comment: @Dunham: `tuple(numpy.zeros((3,),dtype=int)) == (0,0,0)` is `True`. So that means that the two are equivalent. Except for reference equality, both should work exactly the same.

Comment: Furthermore perhaps a more elegant way to do this is using `d[(0,)*3]`. More compact...

Comment: `p[(0,)*3]` gives the same result as the original. This is what I needed. However, I am still curious why the numpy version does not work.

Comment: Without describing what exactly doesn't work, you can see how anybody reading your question has a hard time understanding it, right? See if you can create a minimal example that displays the erroneous behavior in order to get your curiosity satisfied.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Originally, I was asking if there is some fundamental difference between the two constructions that I was unaware of. It appears that it is not obvious, so I am trying to reproduce the error on a small script as I mentioned in a previous comment.

Comment: @Dunham The difference is the `numpy` version creates a tuple of `numpy.int64`s instead of regular Python `int`s; this is unlikely to make a difference but can in a few cases, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302946/itertools-does-not-recognize-numpy-ints-as-valid-inputs-on-python-3-6

Comment: @Chris_Rands Could you post your comment as an answer? This was in fact the problem. The `numpy.int64` type led to numerical errors that were being compounded at later stages of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the difference is the `numpy` version creates a `tuple` of `numpy.int64`s instead of regular Python `int`s:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> t1 = (0,0,0)
>>> type(t1[0])
<class 'int'>
>>> t2 = tuple(numpy.zeros((3,),dtype=int))
>>> type(t2[0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

This is unlikely to make a difference but can in a few cases, for example with [some `itertools` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302946/itertools-does-not-recognize-numpy-ints-as-valid-inputs-on-python-3-6). There is a related [bug issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue30537) on this too, so watch this space.